# Reading and Writing XML per Recipient

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

The error: `{"Token StartElement in state End Document would result in an invalid XML document."}` currently gets thrown on the `writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);` line when reading the second client

The desired outcome: I need to read an XML, the top most nodes will be common for each of the recipient nodes and their associated subsequent nodes(Message and Details). So basically I need to create a XML for each recipient with their subsequent Message and Detail elements.

The top, common XML,
`<!--Data Design : \Data\GenericLetter\Data\DSIletter-->
<!--Input Design : CSF Standard XML-->
<FILE NAME="DSIletter" version="14.0.0.112"`.....

The XML(there are subsequent nodes under recipient, Message and details):
[image]

I can read the first client fine but I get the error mentioned above when trying to read the second client...

The C#:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\GRPAdmin\Desktop\DSIGenericLetterBatch.xml");

string thisClientXML = "";
string sXMLStartElement = "";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
ws.Indent = true;
ws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
ws.CheckCharacters = false;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws);
XmlWriter writerStart = null;

bool FirstClient = true;

while (reader.Read())
{
    int lineNumber = reader.LineNumber;

    if (reader.HasAttributes && reader.GetAttribute(0) == "Recipient")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NEW CLIENT");
        if (FirstClient)
        {
            FirstClient = false;
            sXMLStartElement = output.ToString() + ">";
            writerStart = writer;
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();

            thisClientXML = output.ToString();
            output.Clear();
            output.Length = 0;
            //output.Append(sXMLStartElement.Remove(sXMLStartElement.Length - 1, 1));
            output.Append(sXMLStartElement);
            //writer.Close();
            writer = null;
            // writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws);

            writer = writerStart;

        }
    }

    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
    break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
    writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
    break;
        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
    break;
        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
    break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
    break;
    }
    writer.Flush();

    if (reader.HasAttributes)
    {
        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
        {
             writer.WriteAttributeString(reader.Name, reader.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```html
<!--Data Design : \Data\GenericLetter\Data\DSIletter-->
<!--Input Design : CSF Standard XML-->
<FILE NAME="DSIletter" version="14.0.0.112" State="WIP" Template="DSIGenericLetter V2" origin="designer" __IntuitionUser="admin" __InputID="8f5599ef-fe08-48ea-9b44-075a95c5cfbf">
  <REC NAME="Recipient">
    <FLD NAME="FirstName">James</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="LastName">McLeman</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Company">DSI</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Reference">2131231243257657</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="JobDescription">Director</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address1">5 Fintry Court</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address2">Kellyville</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address3">NSW</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="PostCode">2155</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Brand">DSI</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Amount">999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeFormText">Have a great day</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text3">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number3">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="MarketingMessageKey">Boat</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="EditState">DocMode</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Panel">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="EmailAddress">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Mobile">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Balance">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="BirthDate">01/01/1980</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="MaritalStatus">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="DueDate">20130705</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Excess">1000</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Subject">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Gender">Male</FLD>
  </REC>
  <REC NAME="Message">
    <FLD NAME="Key">Introduction</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text3">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text4">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">999999999999999999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">999999999999999999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number3">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number4">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeText">---</FLD>
  </REC>
  <REC NAME="Details">
    <FLD NAME="Key">default</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Description">description</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1"> xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2"> xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeFormText"> xxx</FLD>
  </REC>

    <FLD NAME="Key">default</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Description">support</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1"> xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2"> xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeFormText"> xxx</FLD>
  </REC>

  <REC NAME="Recipient">
    <FLD NAME="FirstName">Fred</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="LastName">McLeman</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Company">DSI</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Reference">2131231243257657</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="JobDescription">Director</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address1">5 Fintry Court</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address2">Kellyville</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address3">NSW</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="PostCode">2155</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Brand">DSI</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Amount">999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeFormText">Have a great day</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text3">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number3">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="MarketingMessageKey">Boat</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="EditState">DocMode</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Panel">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="EmailAddress">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Mobile">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Balance">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="BirthDate">01/01/1980</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="MaritalStatus">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="DueDate">20130705</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Excess">1000</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Subject">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Gender">Male</FLD>
  </REC>
  <REC NAME="Message">
    <FLD NAME="Key">Introduction</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1">Our core services</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text3">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text4">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">999999999999999999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">999999999999999999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number3">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number4">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeText">---</FLD>
  </REC>
  <REC NAME="Details">
    <FLD NAME="Key">default</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Description">description</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1"> xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2"> xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeFormText"> xxx</FLD>
  </REC>

  <REC NAME="Recipient">
    <FLD NAME="FirstName">James</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="LastName">McLeman</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Company">DSI</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Reference">2131231243257657</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="JobDescription">Director</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address1">5 Fintry Court</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address2">Kellyville</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Address3">NSW</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="PostCode">2155</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Brand">DSI</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Amount">999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeFormText">Have a great time in Bora Bora.</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text3">xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number3">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="MarketingMessageKey">Boat</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="EditState">DocMode</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Panel">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="EmailAddress">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Mobile">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Balance">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="BirthDate">01/01/1980</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="MaritalStatus">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="DueDate">20130705</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Excess">1000</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Subject">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Gender">Male</FLD>
  </REC>
  <REC NAME="Message">
    <FLD NAME="Key">Introduction</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1">our fantastic services</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text3">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text4">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">999999999999999999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">999999999999999999.99</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number3">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number4">X</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeText">---</FLD>
  </REC>
    <FLD NAME="Key">default</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Description">description</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number1">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Number2">0</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text1">No GST</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="Text2"> xxx</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="FreeFormText"> xxx</FLD>
  </REC>
</FILE>
```

Comment: You seem to have chosen a very difficult way of creating new XML from existing XML. Ever considered using XSLT? On topic: I'm not certain (can't repro without input text doc), but you seem to be writing `>` to the same output stream you are writing XML to (through `sXMLStartElement`, which contains more than just the name and is appended through other means than XMLWriter). If you must use this approach, try writing to the output using *only* XMLWriter methods. Also, you really want to set `CheckCharacters` to **true**, or you may end up with invalid XML.

Comment: I have added the XML. 
Could you possibly point me in the direction of some resources using XSLT to achieve something similar?

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on the Internet, and a few on the [tag:xslt] info page on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the writer - you are doing 'writer.WriteEndDocument()' and then later trying to write another start element to the writer, and the error is telling you that you can't write anything after the end.

It appears that most of that logic in the 'else' (after the 'if (FirstClient)') should be moved down to the end of the code, after the main 'while' loop.  Once you're done with all reading/writing, THEN call writer.Flush() and writer.WriteEndDocument().